# Is there any single word to name the people who are in an exodus?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, semantics, poetry

We know about the situation called - exodus. But is there any single word to name the people who are in that exodus? I mean, is there any single word to describe people who are leaving a place in mass for better situation or for any otehr reason?

Comment: It depends on why they're leaving: *migrant*, *refugee*, *returnee*, etc.

Comment: "Refugee" is probably the closest, but look at the synonyms of that word.

Comment: Note that, in another sense, the people of an exodus (especially The Exodus) might be called "wanderers".

Comment: As a group, particularly if they don't all move to the same place, they might be referred to as a *diaspora*.

Comment: Exodic dancers.

Comment: That's two words. :-)

Comment: One specific group was called [Exodusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodusters), "African Americans who migrated from states along the Mississippi River to Kansas in the late nineteenth century". Of course Israelites would refer to another well-known group. Exodus has a lot of different meanings.

Comment: No one has mentioned the cognate 'exile'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to M-W, an [*exodus*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exodus) is "a mass departure: EMIGRATION", where [EMIGRATION](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emigration) means "an act or instance of emigrating : departure from a place of abode, natural home, or country for life or residence elsewhere." This suggests [**émigré**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emigre) as an appropriate answer. It has the advantage of being more general than words like *refugee* (one could emigrate for any number of reasons), but like *refugee* and other words, it need not always connote the idea of a mass departure, although it often does.

Comment: In other words, there is **no** derivative of *exodus* that can be used for such people; nor any term that would cover everybody who is in any kind of an exodus. These people have to be referred by some term or other that captures the nature of the particular exodus they are in. The term *émigré* is typically used for those who **have** emigrated some time ago, rather than those who are currently in the process of emigrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "exodees" used to mean this though I can't recall where. None of the suggested words has precisely that meaning so one is definitely needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).